# drupal user warning includes/bootstrap.inc

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, warnings

I apologize if this is not the right form for asking this question.

I just downloaded and installed the Panopoly distribution on to my laptop using Mamp.
I increased the memory limit to the recommended 196.
After the install I have been receiving User Warnings saying that modules are missing.

(line 1128 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/panopoly/includes/bootstrap.inc).

How do I fix this?

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: are you using extra vhost ?

Comment: I'm not sure what extra vhost is. If you're asking if I'm doing virtual hosting, I don't believe so. I'm just running it on my Mac laptop using MAMP.

Comment: follow this tuto http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php , i think you have to activate some apache mods like rewrite_mod etc..

Comment: Thanks that worked, not sure why though?

Comment: in most cases , mod_rewrite is used by framework or library , and for developer it's a reflex to activate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer with this tuto http://www.foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php , i think you have to activate some apache mods like rewrite_mod etc..